# Merge 2 spark dataframes with non overlapping columns

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

I have two data frames, df1:

```
+---+---------+
| id| col_name|
+---+---------+
|  0|      a  |
|  1|      b  |
|  2|     null|
|  3|     null|
|  4|      e  |
|  5|      f  |
|  6|      g  |
|  7|      h  |
|  8|     null|
|  9|      j  |
+---+---------+
```

and df2:

```
+---+---------+
| id| col_name|
+---+---------+
|  0|     null|
|  1|     null|
|  2|        c|
|  3|        d|
|  4|     null|
|  5|     null|
|  6|     null|
|  7|     null|
|  8|        i|
|  9|     null|
+---+---------+
```

and I want to merge them so I get

```
+---+---------+
| id| col_name|
+---+---------+
|  0|        a|
|  1|        b|
|  2|        c|
|  3|        d|
|  4|        e|
|  5|        f|
|  6|        g|
|  7|        h|
|  8|        i|
|  9|        j|
+---+---------+
```

I know for sure that they aren't overlapping (ie when df2 entry is null df1 entry isn't and vise versa)

I know that if I use join I won't get them on the same column and will instead get 2 "col_name". I just want it on the one column. How do I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
df1.alias("a").join(df2.alias("b"), "id").selectExpr("id", "coalesce(a.col_name, b.col_name) as col_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
mydf = df1.copy()                                     #make copy of first array
idx = np.where(df1['col_name'].values == 'null')[0]   #get indices of null
val = df2['col_name'].values[idx]                     #get values from df2 where df1 is null
mydf['col_name'][idx] = val                           #assign those values in mydf
mydf                                                  #print mydf
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to utilize the [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#coalesce) function to achieve this.

```scala
df1 = df1.withColumnRenamed("col_name", "col_name_a")
df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed("col_name", "col_name_b")

joinedDF = renamedDF1.join(renamedDF2, "id")
joinedDF = joinedDF.withColumn(
        "col_name", 
        coalesce(joinedDF.col("col_name_a"), joinedDF.col("col_name_b"))
    )
```